# Android: Can I use Design Support Library instead of AppCompat for Material Design UI?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, androiddesignsupport

I think I may have misunderstood online documentation, but there are many on implementing Material Design for Android Apps using Android Design Support Library.

I have an app with minimum SDK of 14, that I am ok with increasing to 16. I don't use Coordinator Layout or anything, but have the following dependencies for Material Design Theme and Snackbar.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

I was wondering whether I could remove dependency to AppCompat, and instead just use Design Support Library, to implement the Material Design Theme, but am unable to find how to get this. Or have I understood this incorrectly?

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: I dont think you have to remove that dependency. Any unsed code will just be removed by proguard (if you enabled it) anyway. So removing it that ways isn't worth it in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ommit the `appcompat` dependency since `design` has a dependency on it. To verify that you can use the gradle dependency tree. Here it how it looks like. I am using `com.android.support:design:24.2.1`

```
+--- com.android.support:design:24.2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:24.2.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.2.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.1 (*)
```

To use it yourself

Gradle (top-right-tab) -> Execute Gradle Task (gradle symbol) -> make sure you are in `:app` -> run `app:dependencies`

So `com.android.support:design:25.3.1` will have `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` as a dependency.

Comment: I guess your reply indirectly answers my question that it is not possible to do without either, since I need Snackbar and that depends on AppCompat for pre-sdk-22. It doesn't bother me terribly, but it seemed overkill to have an entire support library just for Material Design Theme. Any alternative? I could probably do without Snackbar.

Comment: @ShahidThaika The support libraries are always a great idea to use since they are usually backwards compatible. Your own solution might be obsolete on the next sdk update.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `AppCompat`, as it will adapt everything in older versions of Android. It also depends on the `View`s you are going to use. If it is an ordinary `Button` or `EditText`, there is no need for `AppCompat`, since all Android versions support them.